# How do I loop through id in a function and get the results in vue.js and Graph ql query?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, graphql, graphql-js

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66tAg.png)How to loop through id in a function and get the results in vue.js and Graph ql query?

i want to return value based on the fsID(id) from graph ql query in Vuejs,...my return value should contain all the values from the query

```
const getLogData = async () => {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(AppObj.Appid, child => {
      var fsId = AppObj.Appid // getting data from somewhere on the code ad assigning it to var fs id to execute graph QL query
      debugger
      console.log(fsId)
      const query2 = `
      query( $fsId: ID!){
     
      agEvents(fsId : $fsId )
      
      {
        edges
        {
          node
          {
            id
            eventType
            
            user
            {
              id                 
              email
                               
            }                
          }
        }
        
      }
    }
  }
  `
      debugger
      const variables = { fsId }
      lx.executeGraphQL(query2, variables).then(function (result2) {
        var logObj = {}
        logObj.id = fsId
        logObj.logdata = result2
      })
    })
  }
  console.log(getLogData)// need all my results as a return here
```

i want to return value based on the fsID(id) from graph ql query in Vuejs,...my return value should contain all the values from the query

i have tried like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdk5w.png) ,but then Lx is not able to reach

Comment: What is `lx` ? It is not clear for community.

Comment: Given `lx.executeGraphQL(query2, variables)` returns a promise, you're looking for `Promise.all`. Do not use `forEach`.

Comment: lx is globally available instance variable.....if i cant use foreach,,, how can i write it,,, can you please help @Bergi

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.